# Request is not working for me

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why this request doesn't work.

```
$query ="UPDATE $this->tabdata SET ";
foreach ($this->dataedit as $key => $value) {
 $query .= "".$key."  = '".$value."', ";
}

$pat ="+-0*/";
$query .= $pat;
$query = str_replace(", ".$pat," ", $query)  ;
$query .=" WHERE  id = '$id' ";
echo $query;
$sql = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: what is preview of `$query`? can you post it.

Comment: have you connected to your db? also dont do that `"+-0/"` and `str_replace` magic to just remove the last `,` just do a `trim($query," ,");`

Comment: Consider not to use string manipulation to make SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query ="UPDATE $this->tabdata SET ";
foreach ($this->dataedit as $key => $value) {
 $query .= "".$key."  = '".$value."', ";
}

$pat ="+-0*/";
$query .= $pat;
$query = str_replace(", ".$pat," ", $query)  ;
$query .=" WHERE  id = '{$id}' ";//modify'$id' to '{$id}',try again 
echo $query;
$sql = mysql_query($query);
```

link [Strings's  single quoted part](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: please, *please*, dont copy paste other answers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22851507/953684 you even having variable names from that other answer copied here.

Comment: @Sharky so sorry，that i answer the same question http://stackoverflow.com/a/22826690/1969039 .but linked wrong to others answer